# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'EC180'

Tags: python, pandas

All that i tried was:

```
df['buyer_zip']=df['buyer_zip'].replace('-', 0)
df['buyer_zip']=df['buyer_zip'].replace('', 0)
df['buyer_zip']=df['buyer_zip'].str[:5]
df["buyer_zip"].fillna( method ='ffill', inplace = True)
df["buyer_zip"].apply(int)
```

I have two columns in a pandas dataframe called Buyer_zip and Item_zip which are the zip codes of Buyer and items respectively. These zip codes have 4 formats. One is 5 digit zip code( ex: 12345), one is 5+4 digit zip code( 12345-1234), one is 9 digit zipcode (123456789) and the last one is 'EC180'. So, the last format is alphanumeric. There are 15 Million records in total. I am struck at a point where i have to convert all those alphanumeric values to numeric. When trying to do the same, i encountered the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'EC180'. Could someone help me how to find all the words in my data column and replace it with 00000. Appreciate any help.But none of it gave an answer to how to find the words in that column and replace it with numbers

Sample data:

```
buyer_zip 
97219 
11415-3528 
EC180
907031234
```

**Expected output**

```
     buyer_zip
0      97219
1  114153528
2          0
3  907031234
```

Comment: Include a sample of the dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: It has a lot of records--15 Million.So unable to attach anything

Comment: Please pull your question out of the code.  It makes it impossible to know what you're asking.

Comment: 15 million is quite a bit to post. But you've got 4 types so how about a df with 1 column and 4 rows. Maybe a few more rows to show different examples of the alphabetic one you are having problem with.

Comment: @QuangHoang-- Added that piece of code in my question now

Comment: @QuangHoang - The question was reasonably clear ... the need to handle the alphabetic entreis.

Comment: buyer_zip
97219
11415-3528
EC180'
907031234

@tdelaney--the above is the formats of all

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you can't convert `EC180` to integer. What number would you expect from that string?

Comment: i just want to convert all such strings to 00000 a default zipcode @QuangHoang

Comment: @VasudhaPasumarthi please click `edit` under your question and update your expected output. Then I would vote to re-open your question.

Comment: @QuangHoang - The original post said to replace it with "00000".

Comment: @QuangHoang - Man you are harsh!

Comment: I changed the output to what I think is correct.

Comment: Voted to reopen as the question has been updated properly.

Comment: @tdelaney please understand that I'm not particularly strict. OP is a new comer, and I already put a based line for him. The pratice of asking a good question is really helping others. Beside, I don't think you updating the expected output would really be what OP wants, he said the string `"00000"` as default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has several different "replace" methods. On a `DataFrame` or a `Series`, replace is meant to match and replace entire values. For instance, `df['buyer_zip'].replace('-', 0)` looks for a column value that is literally the single character "-" and replaces it with the integer 0. That's not what you want. The series also has a `.str` attribute which holds functions for strings, and *its* `replace` is closer to what you want.

But, that *is* what you want when you have a string that starts with a non-digit letter. You want that one to be completely replaced with "00000".

Finally, `astype` is a faster way to convert the column to an int.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"buyer_zip":["12345", "123451234", "123456789", "EC180"]})

df["buyer_zip"] = df["buyer_zip"].str.replace("-", "")
df["buyer_zip"] = df["buyer_zip"].replace(r"[^\d].*$", "00000", regex=True)
df["buyer_zip"] = df["buyer_zip"].astype(int)
```

The operations can be chained. Apply the second operation to the result of the first, etc, and you can condense the conversion

```
df["buyer_zip"] = df["buyer_zip"].str.replace("-", "").replace(r"[^\d].*$", "00000", regex=True).astype(int)
```